# Update column depending if other column value is in list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im working with a data set that needs some manual cleanup.
One thing that i need to do is assign a certain value in one column to some of my rows, if in another column, that row has a value that is present in a list ive defined.

So here a reduced example of what i want to do:

```py
to_be_changed = ['b','e','a']

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,2,1,2],'col2':['a','b','c','d','e' ]})

# change col1 in all rows which label shows up in to_be_changed to 3
```

So the desidered modified Dataframe would look like:

```
  col1 col2
0    3    a
1    3    b
2    2    c
3    1    d
4    3    e
```

---

My closest attempt to solving this is:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df=='b' ,3,df)
  ,index=df.index,columns=df.columns)
```

Which produces:

```
 col1 col2
0    1    a
1    2    3
2    2    c
3    1    d
4    2    e
```

This only changes col2 and obviously only the rows with the hardcoded-label `'b'`.

I also tried:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df in to_be_changed ,3,df)
  ,index=df.index,columns=df.columns)
```

But that produces an error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_11084/574679588.py in <cell line: 4>()
      3 df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,2,1,2],'col2':['a','b','c','d','e' ]})
      4 df = pd.DataFrame(
----> 5   np.where(df in to_be_changed ,3,df)
      6   ,index=df.index,columns=df.columns)
      7 df

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1525     @final
   1526     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1527         raise ValueError(
   1528             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1529             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use pandas `loc` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)), using the same `isin()` function:

```py
import pandas as pd

to_be_changed = ['b','e','a']
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,2,1,2],'col2':['a','b','c','d','e' ]})

df.loc[df['col2'].isin(to_be_changed), 'col1'] = 3
```

produces the expected output:

```py
   col1 col2
0     3    a
1     3    b
2     2    c
3     1    d
4     3    e
```

I find it usefull because you can change several columns at once given the same condition.

```py
import pandas as pd

to_be_changed = ['b','e','a']
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,2,1,2],'col2':['a','b','c','d','e' ],'col2':[5,6,7,8,9]})

df.loc[df['col2'].isin(to_be_changed), ['col1','col3']] = [3,0]
```

which  gives you:

```py
   col1 col2  col3
0     3    a     0
1     3    b     0
2     2    c     7
3     1    d     8
4     3    e     0
```

However for large dataframes, `np.where` is probably faster... but I didn't check.

Comment: Thank you, that's basically exactly what I was looking for!  My data frame is only ~ 300 rows so performance isn't a huge issue. Perfect

Answer (score 1):

use `numpy.where` like this

```
import numpy as np
to_be_changed = ['b','e','a']

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,2,1,2],'col2':['a','b','c','d','e' ]})

df["col1"] = np.where(df["col2"].isin(to_be_changed), 3, df["col1"])

# output
  col1  col2
0   3   a
1   3   b
2   2   c
3   1   d
4   3   e
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# which rows need to be changed?
m = df['col2'].isin(to_be_changed)

# update those specifically
df.loc[m, ['col1']] = 3
```

output:

```
   col1 col2
0     3    a
1     3    b
2     2    c
3     1    d
4     3    e
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[(df["col2"]=="a")|(df["col2"]=="b")|(df["col2"]=="e"), "col1"]=3
```